# How can I get devise invitable to use a different devise mailer I set in the config file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, invitation

In devise invitable, the invite! method does the following:

```
def invite!
        if new_record? || invited?
          self.skip_confirmation! if self.new_record? && self.respond_to?(:skip_confirmation!)
          generate_invitation_token if self.invitation_token.nil?
          self.invitation_sent_at = Time.now.utc
          save(:validate => false)
          ::Devise.mailer.invitation_instructions(self).deliver
        end
      end
```

However, because I wanted devise to use PostageApp, I created a new mailer called new_devise_mailer.rb which is basically the same as devise mailer, but inherits PostageApp.

In the config/initialization/devise.rb file, I set config.mailer = "NewDeviseMailer" instead of "Devise:Mailer"

How can the invitable module know to use the new mailer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The invitable module should automatically use `NewDeviseMailer` since it calls `Devise.mailer`, not `Devise::Mailer` and you changed the default mailer in the initializer.

Comment: okay, I see, so Devise.mailer will point to NewDeviseMailer.  Does NewDeviseMailer have to inherit the DeviseMailer, or can I do as I described, which is to have the methods the same, but it inherits from postageApp instead of from ActionMailer?

Comment: From what I understand of [this discussion](http://help.postageapp.com/discussions/support/176-how-can-i-make-the-devisemailer-a-subclass-of-postageapp), I think you could try `class NewDeviseMailer < PostageApp::Mailer` and do something like `extend Devise::Mailer` to make the Devise mailer class methods available.